# how can i verify texts on page in sequence order in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

there are three lines of text on the web page. I need to verify each line of text and I  have to verify that the first line of text is first on-page  there is no text before it and the second line is located in the second line and so on, Selenium WebDriver
any solution for this

Comment: 1) What have YOU tried so far? 2) Start accepting given you excellent answers. This may increase your chances getting answers

Comment: i have got  WebElements of all Texts. I tried to use  List but each WebElemnt has a specific location. so it's hard to get them and verify them in sequence order.